# Why the JFrame is still not transparent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency, opacity

I am using Java 6.

I hope the following code can show a transparent window. But it still shows a normal window with white background. Why? I think it is logical that if I hide all panes, it should give me a transparent window.

```
package MaskingEffect;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GlassMaskTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                GlassMaskFrame frame=new GlassMaskFrame();

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setVisible(false);
                frame.getLayeredPane().setVisible(false);
                frame.getRootPane().setVisible(false);
                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                //AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(frame, 0.1f);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And here is the `GlassMaskFrame`:

```
package MaskingEffect;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.Container;

public class GlassMaskFrame extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GlassMaskFrame() {

        this.setSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
    }

}
```

I also tried to `setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))` for each of the 4 panes. But still don't get a transparent window.

I don't want to use the `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity()` method.

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: because you setVisible(false); for everything that can be opaque or transparent, in Java7 and never versions 1st JFrame (it can't be visible) must be undecorated, then is possible to playing with rest of ...

Comment: follows Oracle tutorial for working code example

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry I missed mentioning I am using Java 6.

Comment: then everything is possible, can't see for why reason opacity or transparency won't works :-),

Comment: *"I am using Java 6."*  ***Why*** use an obsolete version of Java?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Personally I don't want to but that's a legacy code issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color of your frame to

```
<frame-name>.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

And set the opacity of the content pane or whatever you are using...

```
<content-pane-name>.setOpaque(false);
```

this might do the trick....

Comment: Seems promising. Only that I didn't find the `setOpaque()` method. Which Java version are you using?

Comment: `setOpaque()` is for content pane, not frame

Comment: Maybe that's JDK8 only. I am using JDK6.

Answer (score 0):

```
public TransparentJFrame()
{
setTitle("Transparent JFrame Demo");
setSize(400,400);
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
//For Java 1.7 or above
setOpacity(0.4f);
//For lower java versions
//com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this,0.4f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I heard that AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity() is not recommended. Though I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier with Java 7+, with Java 6, you need to use the private API `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities`

For this, I wrote a utility class which makes it much easier to use.  It uses reflection to determine if it's possible to actual call, in case you're using a version of Java below 6u10

```
public static boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {

    boolean support = false;

    try {

        Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
        support = true;

    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }

    return support;

}

public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

    try {

        Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
        if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

            Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
            method.invoke(null, window, opaque);

        }

    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }

}

public static void setOpacity(Window window, float opacity) {

    try {

        Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
        if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

            Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpacity", Window.class, float.class);
            method.invoke(null, window, opacity);

        }

    } catch (Exception exp) {

        exp.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public static float getOpacity(Window window) {

    float opacity = 1f;
    try {

        Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
        if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

            Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("getWindowOpacity", Window.class);
            Object value = method.invoke(null, window);
            if (value != null && value instanceof Float) {

                opacity = ((Float) value).floatValue();

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception exp) {

        exp.printStackTrace();

    }

    return opacity;

}
```

## Opaque

[image: Opaque]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                setOpaque(frame, false);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Look no hands"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {

        boolean support = false;

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            support = true;

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

        return support;

    }

    public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                method.invoke(null, window, opaque);

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

    }

    public static void setOpacity(Window window, float opacity) {

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpacity", Window.class, float.class);
                method.invoke(null, window, opacity);

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {

            exp.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public static float getOpacity(Window window) {

        float opacity = 1f;
        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("getWindowOpacity", Window.class);
                Object value = method.invoke(null, window);
                if (value != null && value instanceof Float) {

                    opacity = ((Float) value).floatValue();

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {

            exp.printStackTrace();

        }

        return opacity;

    }

}
```

## Transparent

[image: Transparent]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                setOpacity(frame, 0.5f);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Look no hands"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public static boolean supportsPerAlphaPixel() {

        boolean support = false;

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            support = true;

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

        return support;

    }

    public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                method.invoke(null, window, opaque);

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {
        }

    }

    public static void setOpacity(Window window, float opacity) {

        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpacity", Window.class, float.class);
                method.invoke(null, window, opacity);

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {

            exp.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    public static float getOpacity(Window window) {

        float opacity = 1f;
        try {

            Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
            if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("getWindowOpacity", Window.class);
                Object value = method.invoke(null, window);
                if (value != null && value instanceof Float) {

                    opacity = ((Float) value).floatValue();

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception exp) {

            exp.printStackTrace();

        }

        return opacity;

    }

}
```

Now before you jump all over about the frame's been "borderless", this is away to make it work, but, it may not work on all platforms (like MacOS), it requires you to use a look and feel which supplies the frames borders (like metal for example), which isn't particularly pleasant...

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to draw an opaque rectangle (not filled) on a transparent frame? What I am trying to achieve is some kind of "aiming" effect.

Comment: Or let me put it this way: it's like a rectangle drawn on a piece of glass.

Comment: Yes, but you need to fake it. Basically, you create a transparent window and use a JPanel, which is also transparent. Override the panel's paintComponent method and use an AlphaComposite to paint what you want